# Exception has occurred. ArgumentError (Invalid argument(s) (onError): The error handler of Future.catchError must return a value of the future's type)

Tags: flutter, error-handling, firebase-authentication

I have looked at other sources and I still am not getting the answer. I'm not sure how to begin a try/catch block with what I have. There have been moments where it worked without one, I keep coming back to the same error though.
I have altered little parts of it as I have seen suggested on Stack Overflow and other sources but I am still coming up with the error,

> Exception has occurred.
> ArgumentError (Invalid argument(s) (onError): The error handler of Future.catchError must return a value of the future's type)"

There are two alterations commented out because, they worked for either a time or two then stopped.

The error happens right at the `await fAuth`:

````
signInUser() async {
  showDialog(
      barrierDismissible: false,
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) =>
          const LoadingDialog(messageText: "Logging in..."));

  final User? userFirebase = (await fAuth
          .signInWithEmailAndPassword(
              email: emailTextEditingController.text.trim(),
              password: passwordTextEditingController.text.trim())
          .catchError((errorMsg) {
    Navigator.pop(context);
    // Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: "Error ${errorMsg.toString()}");

   return cMethods.displaySnackBar(errorMsg.toString(), context);
    // return errorMsg;
  }))
      .user;
  if (!context.mounted) return;
  Navigator.pop(context);```
````

From the global file,

```
final FirebaseAuth fAuth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

User? currentFirebaseUser;
```

Comment: Unless the `catchError` handler throws, it needs to return an object of the same type as the non-failure case so that both success and failure cases yield a value.  In general, you shouldn't be using `catchError` at all.  You're already using `await`; just use `await` within `try`-`catch`.